# CLT and boundedness in proabability

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics

Given the Lindeberg-Lévy Central Limit Theroem for i.i.d $X_i$'s,

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mu\right)\overset{d}\rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}

I understand this implies

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mu = O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
\end{equation}

so that when **$\mu=0$**, we have the following boundedness in probability
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = O_P(1)~\Rightarrow~ \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = O_p(\sqrt{n}).
\end{equation}

---

**Question**. What if $\mu$ is not necessarily zero? What can we say about the order of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$? Am I correct in saying that

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = O_p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) + \mu = O_P(1) ~\Rightarrow~ \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i = O_p(n)
\end{equation}

Can we have a better bound than $O_p(n)$?

Comment: The case $X_i\equiv 1$ shows that you cannot have a better bound.